# Create basic Rake Tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rakefile

I'm new to Ruby. I want to create simple Rake task for creating user with custom password. I tried this code:

```
namespace :users_create do

  @passwd = 'trest333'

  task create_users: :environment do

    Rake::Task["create_cust:create_cust"].invoke

  end

  task :create_users, [:char] => :environment do |environment, args|

    value = args[:char].to_s

    if value.to_s.strip.length != 0

      @passwd = value

      Rake::Task["create_cust:create_cust"].invoke

    end 
  end

  task create_cust: :environment do

    a = User.new
      a.password = @passwd
      a.save()

      puts "password is #{@passwd}"
  end

end
```

But when I run the code using this command rake create_cust:create_cust[some_new _pass] the sitcom password is not used. How I can override the variable @passwd if I send CLI argument?

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't specify passwords on the command line as it may be saved in your session history which is a security risk. I recommend that you create a task that prompts the user for the necessary information, creates the model and reports errors, if any. My approach looks like:

```
def prompt(message)
  print(message)
  STDIN.gets.chop
end

namespace :users do
  task :create => :environment do
    email = prompt('Email: ')
    password = prompt('Password: ')

    user = User.new(email: email, password: password)
    unless user.save
      STDERR.puts('Cannot create a new user:')
      user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
        STDERR.puts(" * #{message}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Depending on your needs, you may extend it by not prompting for arguments specified on the command line (e.g. email).

Answer (score 0):

if you use zsh you need to pass parameters to rake task like this: `create_cust:create_cust\[some_new _pass\]`.